# Apache Camel EofSensorInputStream org.apache.hc.core5.http.StreamClosedException: Stream already closed

Tags: apache-camel

After upgrade to Camel 4.0.0-M3, some of the routes are getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hc.core5.http.StreamClosedException: Stream already closed
at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:162)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:148)
at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:193)
at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:161)
at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:156)
at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copyAndCloseInput(IOHelper.java:229)
at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copyAndCloseInput(IOHelper.java:225)
at org.apache.camel.converter.stream.StreamCacheConverter.convertToStreamCache(StreamCacheConverter.java:54)
at org.apache.camel.converter.stream.StreamCacheBulkConverterLoader.doConvertTo(StreamCacheBulkConverterLoader.java:78)
at org.apache.camel.converter.stream.StreamCacheBulkConverterLoader.convertTo(StreamCacheBulkConverterLoader.java:51)

Caused by: org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.EofSensorInputStream to the required type: org.apache.camel.StreamCache with value org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.EofSensorInputStream@3cbd093f due to org.apache.hc.core5.http.StreamClosedException: Stream already closed
at org.apache.camel.converter.stream.StreamCacheBulkConverterLoader.convertTo(StreamCacheBulkConverterLoader.java:60)
at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:447)
at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:350)
at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:189)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultStreamCachingStrategy.cache(DefaultStreamCachingStrategy.java:226)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultStreamCachingStrategy.cache(DefaultStreamCachingStrategy.java:217)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor$StreamCachingAdvice.before(CamelInternalProcessor.java:968)
```

It seems to be related to Camel updating HTTP components to v5.
Also Stream Caching doesn't seem to help.

In version 4.0.0-M2 this does not appear.

The M3 version migrates from HTTP components v4 to v5, it is likely related to that.

Comment: Hard to help without a clear example of a route that fails. Please read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yup, will do so, just thought somebody else will have the same issue already.
I am pretty sure that it is a bug introduced in M3 since in M2 it works.

Comment: Feel free to create directly a ticket with steps to reproduce in the camel bug tracker https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL