# Apache Camel 4 org.apache.hc.core5.http.StreamClosedException: Stream already closed

Tags: apache-camel

*Somewhat a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76366071/apache-camel-eofsensorinputstream-org-apache-hc-core5-http-streamclosedexception), but I provide steps to reproduce*

Since the 4.0.0-M3 update of Apache Camel (when HTTP components were updated to v5), the following use case produces an error.

The problem seems to be related to HttpClient v5 consuming (and then closing) the InputStream, as opposed to v4 which did not.

I am not sure if this could be considered a bug in the Apache Camel HTTP component or if the problem was my use case in the first place.

Nevertheless, I am looking for a solution where I can stream the response of a route's destination (in this example, a file available through an arbitrary URL) through a Spring Boot REST controller, while using minimal memory and disk footprint.

**Route definition**

```
from("direct:test_stream")
  .noStreamCaching()
  .to("http://localhost:8080/test/streamfile?disableStreamCache=true")
  .process(exchange -> {
    OutputStream responseStream = exchange.getProperty("RESPONSE_STREAM", ServletOutputStream.class);
    InputStream inputStream = exchange.getMessage().getBody(EofSensorInputStream.class);
    StreamUtils.copy(inputStream, responseStream);
  });
```

**Route usage**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value ="/test")
@Slf4j
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getFile(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        producerTemplate.send("direct:test_stream", ExchangePattern.InOut, x -> {
            x.setProperty("RESPONSE_STREAM", httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
        });
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/streamfile", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Resource streamFile() throws IOException {
        return new InputStreamResource(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("1.jpg")));
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
org.apache.hc.core5.http.StreamClosedException: Stream already closed
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:176) ~[httpcore5-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135) ~[httpcore5-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.transferTo(InputStream.java:782) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:153) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at com.example.democamel.config.RouteConfiguration$1.lambda$configure$0(RouteConfiguration.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:65) ~[camel-support-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:475) ~[camel-core-processor-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.executeReactiveWork(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:196) ~[camel-base-engine-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:164) ~[camel-base-engine-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59) ~[camel-base-engine-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:163) ~[camel-core-processor-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:383) ~[camel-base-engine-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:96) ~[camel-direct-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:212) ~[camel-base-engine-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.SharedCamelInternalProcessor$1.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:109) ~[camel-base-engine-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:81) ~[camel-base-engine-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:106) ~[camel-base-engine-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.cache.DefaultProducerCache.send(DefaultProducerCache.java:180) ~[camel-support-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:176) ~[camel-base-engine-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:172) ~[camel-base-engine-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:143) ~[camel-base-engine-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at com.example.democamel.controller.TestController.getFile(TestController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

*N.B.: I cannot reproduce this issue on Apache Camel version 3.21.1 nor 4.0.0-M2, only on 4.0.0-M3 and later*